# a function display logarithm of a pdf in matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, probability-theory, probability-density

I need to calculate the density of 50 in a standard normal distribution, actually, the result will return to 0 by `pdf('norm',50,0,1)`, then I try to display the logarithm of it,it doesn't work with `log(pdf('norm',50,0,1))`. In R, we can do like `dnorm(50,log = TRUE)`, any similar function in MATLAB? I did not find it. thanks

Comment: What does not work? Your code seems to be fine. It returns the log of the pdf at 0

Comment: Which is the correct result. The pdf is 0 and log(0) is -Inf

Comment: the correct answer should be -1250.919.

Comment: The value is to small to be represented in a double value, it should be about `5e-544` which is rounded to 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you compute the pdf evaluated at 50, you get 0 because of finite precision (spefically, the result is less than [`realmin`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/realmin.html)). You should compute the logarithm directly. From the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), the logarithm of a standard normal pdf evaluated at 50 is

```
>> format long %// to show more decimals
>> -50^2/2 - .5*log(2*pi)
ans =
   -1.250918938533205e+003
```